# Oracle SQL: Convert Varchar2 to Number and handle Nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert the `CUSER1` column I am pulling from a `VARCHAR2` to a `NUMBER`. Below is the current SQL I am using to see if I can get his to work:

```
SELECT V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.MFGCELL     ,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.MFG_TYPE     ,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.PROD_DATE,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.EQNO,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.SHIFT,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.ARINVT_ID,
  NVL(AVG(
    TO_NUMBER(NVL(V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.CUSER1,0),9999.99)
    ),0) CUSER1    

FROM V_PDAYPROD_CRW1
     LEFT JOIN 
     (
      SELECT REJECTS.DAY_PART_ID D_P_ID,
      SUM(REJECTS.REJECTS) RE
      FROM REJECTS
      GROUP BY REJECTS.DAY_PART_ID
     )
      ON V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.PDAY_PART_ID = D_P_ID


GROUP BY  V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.MFGCELL     ,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.MFG_TYPE     ,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.PROD_DATE,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.EQNO,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.SHIFT,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.ARINVT_ID
```

I keep getting the error `ORA-01722: invalid number`. The values in `CUSER1` are mostly: NULL, 5, 0.33, .25, 1, .1, 0.42, etc...

I am trying to use `TO_NUMBER()` to do this but I can't seem to get it right.

Any suggestions?

> Update I tried casting VARCHAR2 to NUMBER. Still getting INVALID NUMBER

```
SELECT V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.MFGCELL     ,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.MFG_TYPE     ,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.PROD_DATE,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.EQNO,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.SHIFT,
   V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.ARINVT_ID,

   NVL(AVG(CAST(V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.CUSER1 AS NUMBER) ),0) CUSER1        

FROM V_PDAYPROD_CRW1
     LEFT JOIN 
     (
      SELECT REJECTS.DAY_PART_ID D_P_ID,
      SUM(REJECTS.REJECTS) RE
      FROM REJECTS
      GROUP BY REJECTS.DAY_PART_ID
     )
      ON V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.PDAY_PART_ID = D_P_ID

GROUP BY  V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.MFGCELL     ,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.MFG_TYPE     ,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.PROD_DATE,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.EQNO,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.SHIFT,
      V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.ARINVT_ID
```

> Update: Got it working

I am using the following to get it working:

```
COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.CUSER1, '^\d+')), 0)
```

This is getting me the results I want. Thanks @Thorsten_Kettner for guiding me to the right solution.

Comment: What does _mostly_ mean here?

Comment: Sorry. I am just trying to explain that values are NULLs and in different formats of no decimal(5), 2 decimal(0.33), 2 decimal without a leading zero(.25) and so on. I hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Try `AVG(NVL(V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.CUSER1,0))` - it should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately no. Gives back INVALID NUMBER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion may fail at the point. 0.33 is not a valid number in all languages.

You can explicitly specify the point as decimal separator:

```
to_number(cuser1, '99999.999')
```

And maybe you'd even have to trim blanks:

```
to_number(trim(cuser1), '99999.999')
```

But still there may be values that violate the pattern. Then a `WHERE` clause might help to only convert valid numbers. E.g.:

```
where regexp_like(cuser1, '^[[:digit:]]*\.{0,1}[[:digit:]]*$') or cuser1 is null
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense and I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

```
NVL(AVG(
TO_NUMBER(NVL(V_PDAYPROD_CRW1.CUSER1,'0'),'9999.99')
),0) CUSER1
```

try this..

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately it does not work. What I am using at the moment ignores ' and " in certain cases.

Comment: I'll try it now